# angular baseHref no impact on index.html links

Tags: angular, configuration

In angular I used to run my build command with the --base-href \myapp syntax.

Now I updated to angular 13 and this command line property is not anymore available.
So I added the property to angular.json:
...configurations/"test"/baseHref: "\myapp"

But this seems to be not enough. This setting will add a `<base href="/myapp">` in the index.html head tag. But it will not change the other links in index.html like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.5fe3fd16ea7e146e.css">
```

So at runtime i get a 404 because styles....css cannot be found in the root, but should reference "myapp/styles....css".

Where can I set baseHref so it also affects the links in index.html?

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the command line parameter 'base-href' needs to be replaced with the **two** properties 'baseHref' and 'deployUrl' in angular.json.

Comment: Where specifically? And especially in Angular 13